# Symfony post form data through endpoint with relationship

Tags: php, forms, api, symfony, post

I have an issue with posting data to Symfony to an endpoint that expects data formatted as a Symfony form.

The endpoint validates the posted data with a Symfony form. Normally, when I have a rendered form with twig. A relationship field will have a structure like this:

```
<select id="form_product" name="form[product]">
   <option value="0" selected="selected">...</option>
   <option value="1">A product</option>
   <option value="2">Some other product</option>
   <option value="3">Product</option>
   <option value="4">Nice product</option>
   <option value="5">Stupid product</option>
   <option value="6">Interesting product</option>
</select>
```

Now I don't have this, I just have an endpoint.

Whenever I want to post a record with say, "Nice product" I could just post a body containing form[product]=4 and the relationship is handled properly. But I only know I should post 4 because I check the rendered form.

The same goes when I need to update a record's relationship to product because I don't know what to send because the values are not related to anything, the option value is just an incremental value regardless of record id or anything.

How is this normally done? How could I manually create a post body containing the relationship of my choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the Symfony form class, you can make the `value` attributes predictable with the [choices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#example-usage) option:

```
$builder->add('product', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Nice product' => 'nice-product', 
        'NOT nice product' => 'not-nice-product'
    ),
));
```

Being aware of this mapping beforehand, you'd then submit a POST with `form[product]='nice-product'`.

Note: the `choices` option also works for the [EntityType form type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choices).

Comment: Ahh, that will probably solve my problem. I'm going to try and work this out and let you know.

Comment: Ok, the choices option does not seem to care, at least on the form side. It still only produces some weird index. Maybe I will have to try the EntityType form type, but I was trying to avoid that because it's part of Symfony and not the form module.

Comment: Ah, I had the first choice set to null, that will create an indexed value. Now I have set it to false and I have control over the choice values.

Comment: Ok, I will have to find a way to make the value into an actual value, but this is helping. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a REST endpoint I assume that you are building a web app with JavaScript, a phone app or similar.

In this cases the normal procedure is that exists one endpoint to list this related entities  and know it.

For example, in a javascript web app I render a form that have a select of this relationated entities, before show this field I call to an endpoint who return the ids and labels from this entities:

```
{
   {“id”: 1, “label”: “value 1”},
   {“id”: 2, “label”: “value 2”}
}
```

After that we render the field with this values and the user select one, and this is if is finally sent to your endpoint.

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a REST endpoint indeed but it's for communication between some of our services. We are not particularly rendering forms in this case.